# MySQL first UPDATE query is very slow, subsequent UPDATE very fast

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a query:

```
Update users set Numreviews = 1 where userID = 12345
```

Both fields 'numreviews' and 'userID' have indexes that help unrelated SELECT queries.

The problem I am experiencing is when running the first UPDATE query. It can take up to 1 minute. When I run it seconds later for another userID it usually takes milliseconds.

This pattern is very consistent.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. This is on MySQL 5.1.11 running on Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter. I've tried restarting IIS many times and restarting the database also.

Comment: If you reverse the order of the 2 statements, is the behavior the same? What about if you run the same update statement twice in a row? What else is running on the computer where MySql is hosted? Perhaps there's a server resource issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the the initial time is things basically waking up, connecting/handshaking etc.

It appears that this can be caused by [how MySQL uses DNS](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/mysql/doc/refman/5.5/en/dns.html). The link explains this in more detail, but basically when you first connect there is a reverse lookup when you first connect. There are a couple of ways to fix this. The easiest (assuming you are running this from an application) is to set up pooling for your application. This is good to do anyway.

You can also start your server with [--skip-name-resolve](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/mysql/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-name-resolve), or increasing your HOST_CACHE_SIZE

Comment: it locks up entire db while its doing the first update. I am thinking is it somehow related to indexes. except I don't understand why it would hang up just with the first update

Comment: Are you sure that the db is locked? Can you remote into your db server to test that?

Comment: well, it depends on your definition of locked. all other queries are being queued while this one is running.

Comment: the slow query log shows Query time: 00:00:48 Rows Examined: 1, lock time 0.

Comment: is that when you ran the command while you remoted into your db server (from the db server itself? Ill edit my response to give more of an explanation of why I am asking

Comment: the server does not start with --skip-name-resolve. it refuses to recognize the root password. 

how can I increase HOST_CACHE_SIZE? Also can you please point me to some documentation on how to set up pooling? Thanks!

Comment: it wouldnt start when added the --skip-name-resolve? did you still pass in your username and password?

Comment: What type of application is this for (its hard to give you a reference to pooling without knowing the language your application is running in.) this is a description of it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool

Comment: yes, when I changed it to --skip-name-resolve and restarted mysql it rejected my password, so the application could not connect to mysql. I had to disable --skip-grant-tables and restart it again, then re-enter my root password. 

it is a coldfusion application, I think pooling is already enabled. It is configured to "Maintain connections across client requests."

Also, I restarted dns just in case it was running slow or something. That also did not help. I am not sure this is a dns issue, but I am no expert.

Comment: yeah it looks like pooling might be enabled by default (I know very little of coldfusion sorry)? http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/database-connections-handled-coldfusion.html

Comment: Did you restart mysqld (the server), or did you try to pass it in with mysql (ths client)?

Comment: I did all this with mysql workbench. It prompted me for a new password and then rejected it.

Comment: I'm not sure where you would set it with that (I havn't used that application before). Maybe where you configure the server instance?

Comment: so, it is still refusing to log me in after I enable --skip-name-resolve. my root is allowed to connect from 'localhost'. so if I enable --skip-name-resolve is now localhost no longer resolved? Do I need to add permission for 'root' from 127.0.0.1 or from my server IP?

Comment: The way that you connect to the database should not change. can you show me the command that you are using to set the server flag when you restart the mysqld server?

Comment: I don't do it with a command prompt. I restart it with mysql workbench or mysql admin console. When I restart it, I see a popup prompting me to enter the root password. After I do, it denies me access (using password "YES").

Comment: I meant could you show me the text that you enter when you set the server flag, or take a screenshot and add it to your question? (I dont have an installation of either of those applications to try this on).

Comment: add root user for IP 127.0.0.1 allowed me to restart the server after setting --skip-name-resolve.

Comment: Johh, so far disabling name resolve has helped the problem, but I need to test some more. Should I enable skip-host-cache also?

Comment: Please flag for cleanup once you're done with this comment thread. I'm only letting it go right now because user1489525 doesn't have enough rep to take it to chat.

Comment: nope. enabling --skip-names-resolve did not help. all queries are in "waiting" state. the update query is in "end" state.

Comment: Are there any constraints associated with the table you are updating, and does this happen only when you update that one table first, or just the first query?

Comment: this is the MySQL bug that was causing the problem: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=39091

Comment: is that the cause? That doesnt seem to explain why it is just the first query, and why there are not issues with it after your first transaction completes